# Get your fingers caught

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Can "You'll catch your fingers in the door!" be used instead of "You're going to get your fingers caught in the door!"?

You want someone to stop closing the door again and again because they might slam the door on their hand/get their fingers caught by accident.

Comment: will and going to have two different functions regardless of the action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine.

Replacing *are going to* with *will* is fine.

Replacing *get X caught in Y* with *catch X in Y* is not always fine, but it works for fingers because you can't catch your fingers the way you catch a ball. (I.e., don't say, "You'll catch the baseball in the door.")

Answer (score -1):

1. You'll catch your fingers in the door!
2. You're going to get your fingers caught in the door!

In #1, “caught” is active transitive, which isn’t really appropriate since it’s the door catching your fingers. However, the listener should know that and will reinterpret it as if you said #2.

Despite it being technically incorrect, #1 is probably more common. Warnings are usually urgent, so we subconsciously prioritize brevity over correctness (or completeness). A simple “watch your fingers!” would be even better.

Comment: Although the door is the immediate agent, the catching of fingers is is a result of “your” action.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch) has "catch a sleeve on a nail" as an example, which seems very similar.